# How to prevent iPad from doing double-click when tapping on button?

Tags: html, ipad, oracle-apex, double-click

I'm sorry if someone already found a solution to that problem, but I couldn't find it, so here I am, begging you for help.

Customer reported an issue, that one action is performed twice when clicking on a button specifically on iPad. Turned out, that all similar buttons on the website work that way - iPad probably just does double-click. Does anybody know how to interpret tapping as one click, instead of two? Is there any javascript solution for that? I can't just disable the button after the first click, because user must have an option, to use it again (it allows to add new record to order).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read these help pages and provide enough information for us to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I've witnessed many people double click/tap on things on web pages.

One solution to this in APEX is to hide the triggering element on click, as the first action in the relevant dynamic action, or as a supplementary action on a button that submits.

[image: hide triggering element dynamic action]